# Ignore Inspection depending on an Attribute

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper

Is there a way to tell ReSharper to ignore specific inspections on all members decorated with a specific attribute?

E.g. ignore MemberCanBePrivate, MemberCanBeReadonly, MissingXMLComment on all members with `MyFancyAttribute`:

```
[MyFancyAttribute("A string parameter")]
public string MyMember;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use annotation attributes to give ReSharper more context when performing annotations. For example, the `MyFancyAttribute` could be marked with the `JetBrains.Annotations.MeansImplicitUseAttribute`, which means that whenever you use `MyFancyAttribute`, ReSharper will no longer mark the member as unused (e.g. `MyFancyAttribute` could be a marker attribute for something to do with Reflection).

You can also use `UsedImplicitlyAttribute` on a public member to say that the marked symbol is used implicitly (reflection, external library that's not part of the solution) and again, ReSharper will not mark it as unused.

And you can use the `PublicAPIAttribute` to state that a public member is not used in this solution, but is used by an external consumer (subtly and semantically different to `UsedImplicitly`) and again, the item is not marked as unused.

However, there isn't an attribute that tells ReSharper to ignore missing XML comments. The best you can do here is to change the severity of the warning, either by alt+enter and change it across the solution, or by using a specially formatted comment, which again, alt+enter can insert for you.